# How to click a figure and save it in a database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, forms, click

I am currently digitalising a form for doctors, where they can input some patients data. The "basics" (check-boxes,radio-button,etc.) were pretty easy to create. I used formtastic for this.

But now to the real problem: the doctors have to mark an area in a circle (it's for breast cancer patients), where the tumor is. On paper this wasn't a problem obviously.

Is it possible to do the same with ruby on rails?
Users have to mark and save the "marked circle" . Also it would be great if the user could edit (remove the mark and/or add another mark) the circle after or before its saved.

I created a little example:

http://i49.tinypic.com/2v2wemu.jpg

(Can't include the image in my post, since I'm a new user, hope this works nevertheless)

Comment: Yes this is possible with javascript, when you click on (say) a picture, you will have a click event, with X and Y coordinates. record these coordinates by javascript and send back to server. and create a overlay circle(picture or other objects)

Comment: Aren't these coordinates different for every screen-solution, etc. ? So that everything is a mess when I open it on my netbook for example?

Comment: can be an offset from 0,0 pixel of your picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more a javascript question.

You will work with images, and what is important to you is the image element itself, its resolution, and how to capture cursor position when a user clicks it.

start with something like

```
$('img').click()
```

and after

jquery [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)